# Mocha reporters don't support parallel mode, does one exist?

Tags: mocha.js, report, reporting, allure, mochawesome

We're using Mocha 8.0 and are running it with the parallel feature.

Mochawesome reporter completely crashes in that mode. And the couple of very simple reporters like json or spec, well they don't do enough for us. We are looking for html output with screenshots we can throw in. Does anyone have any potential solutions? Thanks.

I'm wondering if writing a custom fork of Mochawesome or Allure reporter is the only way around this now.

Comment: I had a similar question for running in parallel on Github actions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67937238/mocha-parallel-jobs-on-github-actions

Comment: we're waiting on https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/pull/4922 to add full support of parallel mode